# Add Negative Margin to Scroll To Id

Tags: html

I am jumping to an Id using domain.com/#section however the scroll needs a negative margin added too the scroll, meaning it scrolls to far down. Is it possible to do this within the URL without using CSS, jquery or javascript.

Comment: nope. if you want to modify a default function, you will need javascript... unless you have some browser that lets you modify it's default behavior

Comment: Short awnser: no, long awnser: nope.

Answer (score 0):

With `domain.com/#section` you are jumping to an anchor.

With pure HTML you can only move the anchor to the position you want to jump to. So move the anchor up if that's the place you want jump to.

In case you change your decision to avoid CSS:

```
<a name="section" style="position: relative; top:-50px"></a>
```

**Edit:** I missed, that you want to do it in the URL.

Then: no